# Scout SDK: custom visual advice images

Tags: android, skmaps

Using Scout SDK 2.5, looking for way to customize visual advice images for navigation. As I understand the visual advice images are generated on the fly and there is no package of images, which can be replaced in order to use custom ones.

Question: is it possible to customize the color of generated on the fly images? I see that they have grey gamma for now, what about to change the gray gamma in different one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images are generated as transparent png – you can style their color scheme via  [renderVisualAdviceImage](http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/android/2.5.0/com/skobbler/ngx/navigation/SKNavigationManager.html#renderVisualAdviceImage(com.skobbler.ngx.navigation.SKCrossingDescriptor,%20java.lang.String,%20com.skobbler.ngx.navigation.SKVisualAdviceColor)) – it should be something similar to the following:

```
public void onVisualAdviceChanged(final boolean firstVisualAdviceChanged, final boolean secondVisualAdviceChanged,
final SKNavigationState navigationState) {          
if (firstVisualAdviceChanged) {
               SKCrossingDescriptor currentImageCrossingDescriptor =
navigationState.getFirstCrossingDescriptor();
               String currentVisualAdviceImage = "[base path of map resouces]/current_advice_image.png";
               final SKVisualAdviceColor firstVisualAdviceColor = new SKVisualAdviceColor();
               firstVisualAdviceColor.setAllowedStreetColor(new
float[]{0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.4f});
               firstVisualAdviceColor.setForbiddenStreetColor(new
float[]{0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.7f});
               firstVisualAdviceColor.setRouteStreetColor(new
float[]{0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1});

SKNavigationManager.getInstance().renderVisualAdviceImage(currentImageCrossingDescriptor,
   currentVisualAdviceImage, firstVisualAdviceColor);

}
```

Where the array expected by SKVisualAdviceColor is made of 0 to 1 values matched to red/green/blue/alpha values.